# Rerun specific build on jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, continuous-integration

I have a project on Jenkins configured to build when a tag like vXX.XX.XX is created on my repository and publish it to my QA.

Case:
 - I publish a tag;
 - My cooworker publish another tag;
 - I need to republish my version;
 - Even if I add new tag on my branch(not cool), there is no changes and Jenkins don't build.

I try to use Rebuild Plugin, but it publish the last tag even if a select my build.

PS: I don't want to add fake commit with white space.

Comment: Instead of committing a fake update (white space or other), you can do an empty commit: git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger notification"

Comment: It's the same. The problem is not a commit with white spaces. The problem is that it will mess my git log.
Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Jenkins job so that in addition of checkout the branch and publish HEAD of it, it will get from the post-receice-hook the tag that been pushed as a job parameter and then will perform git checkout for the tag and publish it to. In that way you'll be able to 'rebuild' the build with your tag.